# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 31.1 GiB for an array with shape (21714, 100) and data type <U3844

Tags: python, pytorch, data-science, crf, bilstm

I am training a BiLSTM CRF model and facing this error on all platform like jupyter notebook, colab, pycharm and even vscode  in ubuntu 22.04.

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 2
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
----> 2     main()

Cell In[34], line 50, in main()
     47 test_data = pd.read_csv(test_path, encoding='utf-8').dropna()
     49 # Get dataset
---> 50 train_dataset = CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRF(sentences=train_data['Sentences'].values,
     51                                        tags=train_data['Tags'].values,
     52                                        sequence_len=SEQ_LEN,
     53                                        transforms=Data2Idx,
     54                                        target_transforms=Data2Idx)
     55 test_dataset = CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRF(sentences=test_data['Sentences'].values,
     56                                       tags=test_data['Tags'].values,
     57                                       sequence_len=SEQ_LEN,
     58                                       transforms=Data2Idx,
     59                                       target_transforms=Data2Idx)
     61 # Get dataloader

File ~threat intel/IOC-Detect/utils/datasets.py:26, in CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRF.__init__(self, sentences, tags, sequence_len, transforms, target_transforms)
     23 self.vocab_size, self.vocab2idx, self.idx2vocab = self.__get_vocabs(sentences, True)
     24 self.tag_size, self.tag2idx, self.idx2tag = self.__get_vocabs(tags)
---> 26 self.sentences, self.tags = self.__data_preprocess(sentences, tags, sequence_len)
     28 self.transforms = transforms(self.vocab2idx) if transforms else None
     29 self.target_transforms = target_transforms(self.tag2idx) if target_transforms else None

File /threat intel//IOC-Detect/utils/datasets.py:49, in CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRF.__data_preprocess(self, sentences, tags, sequence_len)
     48 def __data_preprocess(self, sentences: np.array, tags: np.array, sequence_len: int) -> tuple[np.array, np.array]:
---> 49     sentences = self.__padding(self.__data_std(sentences, True), sequence_len)
     50     tags = self.__padding(self.__data_std(tags), sequence_len)
     52     return sentences, tags

File IOC-Detect/utils/datasets.py:70, in CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRF.__padding(self, datas, sequence_len)
     67         data = np.append(data, ['<PAD>'] * (sequence_len - len(data)))
     68     outputs.extend(data[i:i+sequence_len] for i in range(len(data)-sequence_len+1))
---> 70 return np.array(outputs)
```

used these libraries : import os
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

from model.bilstm_crf import BiLSTM_CRF
from utils.datasets import CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRFWithNgram, CTIDatasetForBiLSTMCRF, Data2Idx

when i reduce array size from 21714 to 1000 then problem solved        but new problem created getting this error
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most
call last)
Cell In[7], line 2
1 if **name** == '**main**':
----> 2     main()
---> 81 train(model=model,
---> 31 print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Train Loss: {train_loss /
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to format all of the code correctly and add appropriate tags for the language and libraries that you are related to this problem.

Comment: Could it be that you simply don't have enough RAM to do this?

Comment: yeah i have only 20GB RAM can we modify code so that less RAM required for specific lines of code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: complete code given here                                                                                                                https://onlinegdb.com/Ao9Ef5ka_